# Email Notify author of posts if content is out of date (older than 6 months)

Tags: email

Email Notify author of posts if content is out of date (older than 6 months)

how can I do this in Wordpress please help!

Comment: You can e.g. set up a task with wp_schedule_event to run once a week, check the ->post_modified_gmt property for over six months old, group these by author and then send each author a list of their old posts. You'll need to write a simple plugin to put the code in.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any example?